# Mongoimport 'error connecting to db servers' for cluster

Tags: mongodb

I'm unable to use mongoimport to load some documents to a cluster hosted by MongoDB. I followed this tutorial [Load File with mongoimport](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/import/mongoimport/) and then used this command in Powershell to try and load my documents:

```
.\mongoimport.exe --host "mongodb://clusterads-shard-00-00-qlf9n.mongodb.net:27017,clusterads-shard-00-01-qlf9n.mongodb.net:27017,clusterads-shard-00-02-qlf9n.mongodb.net:27017/admin?replicaSet=ClusterADS-shard-0" --ssl -u <USER> -p '<PASSWORD>' --authenticationDatabase <AUTHENT> --db adscoursework --collection volcanos --drop --jsonArray --file C:\data\volErups.json
```

This gives the error:

```
[........................] adscoursework.volcanos       0B/844KB (0.0%)
[........................] adscoursework.volcanos       0B/844KB (0.0%)
Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
```

I can connect to the above host using Mongo Shell so I don't understand where the issue is.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing `mongodb://` at the start with `ClusterADS-shard-0/` (which is the replica set) and removing `/admin?...` made it work.